# PyQT: Exit/Complete Second Window Before First Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the following code below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


class Second(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.setGeometry(650,400,400,200)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()


class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.setGeometry(350, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()

        Button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('...', self)
        Button1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.grid.addWidget(Button1, 0, 0, 1, 1)


    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.Second = Second()
        self.Second.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.Second.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I click the button, I want to be able to finish up my action in the second window before continuing on the first. Right now, I can exit out of my first window and the second window remains open. How do you keep on the second window but keep the first window unselectable?

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better please.

Comment: When you run the code, you will get a window with a button. When you click the button, it opens a second window. Now if I exit the first window first, the second window remains open. What I want to happen is for the second window to be exited first before the first window can exit.

Comment: Do you want the first window to be closed without closing the second window or do you want the second window to close when the first window closes?

Comment: I want the first window to be inactive (meaning I can't close it, i can click buttons) until the second window closes. But it that is not possible, then having the second window close when the first one closes would suffice.

Comment: i can't close it, i can't click buttons*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

**- Second must inherit from `QDialog`, pass it as parent to the first window and use `exec_()` instead of show:**

```
class Second(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)

class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.setGeometry(350, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        Button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('...', self)
        Button1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        grid.addWidget(Button1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.Second = Second(self)
        self.Second.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.Second.exec_()
```

**- Change the `windowModality` to `Qt::WindowModal`, activate the flag `Qt::Dialog` and pass it the first window as parent.**

```
class Second(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.Dialog)

class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.setGeometry(350, 200, 1000, 700)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        Button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('...', self)
        Button1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        grid.addWidget(Button1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.Second = Second(self)
        self.Second.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.Second.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. When would you want to use solution or is it preference?

Comment: could you please tell me how to write python on Qt, a i am new to python and found no direct method to write python code on Qt text editor and then run it(ctrl + R)